# Different versions of a font in a FontFace

Tags: css, font-face

I've used http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator to generate various versions (.svn, .eot...) of the font GillSans.

I can now use it like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'GillSansFF';
  src: url('fonts/GillSans.eot');
  src: local('☺'), url('fonts/GillSans.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/GillSans.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/GillSans.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

h1 {
    font-family: "GillSansFF", Calibri, sans-serif;
}
```

Since GillSans includes also "Gill Sans Light" (Bold, Italic, etc), how can I specify the "Light" version? Thanks

*EDIT* The solution, as pointed out, it to use different fonts. To extract the ttf from a single ttc I found this working Python script: http://pastebin.com/QXcAtP24

Comment: I think `font-face` only supports one weight per declaration. You'll need to separate the weights into separate `woff`, `ttf` and `svg` files.

Comment: Add new `font-face` and then specify a new name `font-family:GillSansFF-italic` and add the path to the italic version of the font

Comment: yeah, the problem is that on my system (Mac), I only have one GillSans.ttc (that is a collection of fonts) gathering all the various .ttf Any tool to extract them? thanks

Comment: I don't know of a tool to extract the various weights from the collection. I guess you could buy in the individual TTFs > http://www.webtype.com/font/gill-sans-family/

Answer (score 1):

Just add an extra @font-face declaration for your light font:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'GillSansFF';
  src: url('fonts/GillSans.eot');
  src: local('☺'), url('fonts/GillSans.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/GillSans.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/GillSans.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'GillSansFF';
  src: url('fonts/GillSans-light.eot');
  src: local('☺'), url('fonts/GillSans-light.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/GillSans.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/GillSans-light.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: All weights of the font are in a single TTF.

Comment: Well, it was kind of implied in the question:
"Since GillSans includes also "Gill Sans Light" (Bold, Italic, etc), how can I specify the "Light" version?"

Comment: No need to get shirty, I was pointing out his problem more specifically.